# Get Value of Ajax changed field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call, it looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "index.php?id=70&type=999",
     type: 'post',
     data: form  + '&sort=' + val,
     success: function(response)
          {
            $(".listing").load(location.href + " .listing");
            $(".count").load(location.href + " .count");
          },
          complete: function (response) {
               alert( $(".count").val());
          },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
             alert(xhr.status);
        }
 });
```

So, as you can see 2 classes "listing" and "count" are changing, this works fine. After i am trying to alert the NEW value of the "count" class, but it is always giving me the actual one. And just after the alert, the value changes. But doesn't `complete:` mean that the call is made after the `success:` function? Why the alert is being made first and gives me the old value before the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you're code like this:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "index.php?id=70&type=999",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: form  + '&sort=' + val,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        $(".listing").load(location.href + " .listing");
                        $(".count").load(location.href + " .count", function(){
                              alert( $(".count").val());
                         });
                    },
                    complete: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(xhr.status);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

alert value inside success:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "index.php?id=70&type=999",
     type: 'post',
     data: form  + '&sort=' + val,
     success: function(response)
     {
         $(".listing").load(location.href + " .listing");
         $(".count").load(location.href + " .count", function(){
             alert( $(".count").val());
         });
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         alert(xhr.status);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the `complete` fires after the *first* AJAX request completes, not after the second/third AJAX request which you create by calling `load()`. If you want to know the `.count` value you need to put a callback in the `load()` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php?id=70&type=999",
    type: 'post',
    data: form + '&sort=' + val,
    success: function(response) {
        $(".listing").load(location.href + " .listing");
        $(".count").load(location.href + " .count", function() {
            // get the value here, after load() completes
            console.log($(".count").val());
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Also note that you could improve the code by calling the URL in both `load()` calls just once and then extracting the required information from the response, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php?id=70&type=999",
    type: 'post',
    data: form + '&sort=' + val,
    success: function(response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: location.href,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".listing").html($(html).find('.listing'));
                $(".count").html($(html).find('.count'));
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: Roxoradev gave me the same advice, it is working this way. Thank you guys!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that I just updated my answer to avoid the needless duplicate calls to the same location in 2 `load()` requests